# Use hibernate project with EJB

Tags: hibernate, servlets, jboss, ejb-3.0

My setup:

1. Library using hibernate to work with the database. (ETM)
2. EJB component with local interface to work with the library. (ETMEJB)
3. Web app with servlet using EJB. (ETMWeb)
4. Interfaces for EJB (local List item) ETMEJBClient
5. All of it is inside EAR. (ETMEAR)

ETMEAR:

- --ETM
- --ETMEJB
- --ETMEJBClient
- --ETMWeb

When I use library(ETM) from normal Java application it works alright.

When I try to deploy the whole thing (JBoss 7.1) I get:
http://pastebin.com/gDmiFfhL

I guess what it boils down to is:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Connection cannot be null 
when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

I guess hibernate.cfg.xml is not found. Where should I put it?

I already put a copy in every root of source of every part of application (it's silly but I'm desperate) and it doesn't help.

Maybe this is something else?

Thanks!

Let me know if I can provide more info.

EDIT: My hibernate.cfg.xml (works for accessing library from Java app):
EDIT @ouapdouap : reformated code section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <!-- We're using MySQL database so the dialect needs to MySQL as well-->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:/data/Documents/etm</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

  <!-- This will drop our existing database and re-create a new one.
      Existing data will be deleted! -->
  <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>        

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Names the annotated entity class -->
    <mapping class="com.leonty.etm.domain.Contract"/>    
    <mapping class="com.leonty.etm.domain.Employee"/>  
<mapping class="com.leonty.etm.domain.Job"/>  
<mapping class="com.leonty.etm.domain.Time"/>
```

Comment: Can you post your persistence.xml file ?

Comment: I don't use persistence.xml - my library to access db is separated (ETM) and it uses hibernate.cfg.xml
Is this the correct setup?

Answer (score 0):

I migrated all my config into persistence.xml

I put it into:
ETMEJB/ejbModule/META-INF/persistence.xml

So now my ear deploys.

The thing is when I try to use my hibernate objects from EJB it reads persistence.xml not from META-INF of EJB but from META-INF of ETM library, so I have to put the same file in 2 directories:

ETMEJB/ejbModule/META-INF/persistence.xml - so deployment succeeds
ETM/src/META-INF/persistence.xml - used when application is running

When I first try to use my hibernate object by creating EntityManagerFactory I get following exception:

```
    20:50:47,905 ERROR [SchemaExport] schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction!
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.setJdbcAutoCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:582)
```

Comment: The problem turned out to be in switching to JTA by default, so when I put <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="auto" /> it also sets autocommit to true. When I changed "auto" to "update" problem was solved.